# Drop down menus are messing layout?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create drop down menus Like this 
[image]

I am reached [demo](http://uaepap.org/test/final/HomePage.html) at that page but now when i try to add

```
<ul id="secondarynav">
      <li><a href="#">Pictures</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
</ul>
```

the layout gets messy like [this](http://uaepap.org/test/final/testHomePage.html).I have tried alot but no use may be i am not using box-sizing right on header.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write **vertical-align:top**  is `#nav` . Like this:

```
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none outside none;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: wow it works super fine thanks.please can you give me some link that why it works

Comment: the default value of inline-block is baseline that's why we need to define vertical-align:top, check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/vertical-align